# How do I create a postgresql user with fabric

Tags: postgresql, fabric

I want to create a database user for my setup fabric script but createuser has interactive password entering and seams not to like fabric.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use plain SQL to create a new user:

```
CREATE ROLE user_name WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'your password';
```

Comment: how do I send this SQL to postgres in a one-liner?

Comment: Connect with the psql client and send the query. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/app-psql.html

Answer (score 35):

To extend the answer with a Fabric example...

```
# In fabfile.py
def create_database():
    """Creates role and database"""
    db_user = get_user()  # define these
    db_pass = get_pass()
    db_name = get_db_name()
    sudo('psql -c "CREATE USER %s WITH NOCREATEDB NOCREATEUSER " \
         "ENCRYPTED PASSWORD E\'%s\'"' % (db_user, db_pass), user='postgres')
    sudo('psql -c "CREATE DATABASE %s WITH OWNER %s"' % (
         db_name, db_user), user='postgres')
```

Comment: Upwote. But did you really mean table in `db_table = get_table()`? Looks like you meant a database name.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably of some use without having to write your own modules or you could use it as reference.

```
from fabtools import require

require.postgres.create_db ???
```

https://fabtools.readthedocs.org/en/0.19.0/api/require/postgres.html?highlight=postgres#module-fabtools.require.postgres