# Automate web app setup

Tags: python, deployment

I created a python flask app that connects to an existing Postgres database and displays reports. I want to deploy the app to multiple Linux virtual machines in a simple way.

What is the best way to do this? The steps involved are:

1. Create a Postgres user and grant read only access to the existing database
2. Create python virtual environment and download git repository into it
3. Install supervisor and create config file to ensure the app runs without a terminal window and after system restarts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fabric.
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/tutorial.html#defining-connections

[How do I create a postgresql user with fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665743/how-do-i-create-a-postgresql-user-with-fabric)

[Activate a virtualenv via fabric as deploy user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180411/activate-a-virtualenv-via-fabric-as-deploy-user)